# I have an error in C++ when I write my code: Error 1 error C2601: 'circle' : local function definitions are illegal

Tags: c++

I have a problem in C++ when I write this code:

```
error C2601: 'circle' : local function definitions are illegal
```

How can I find a solution to the problem?

```
#include < iostream > 
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char grade;
    cout << "enter grade : ";
    cin >> grade;
    switch (grade) {
    case 'A':
        void circle(float &, float &, float);
        {
            float r, a, c;
            cout << "enter radius:";
            cin >> r;
            circle(a, c, r);
            cout << "area=" << a << "\t" << "circumference=" << c << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        void circle(float & area, float & circumference, float r)
        {
            const double pi = 3.14159;
            area = pi * r * r;
            circumference = 2 * pi * r;
        }
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid grade" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Your grade is " << grade << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could find the solution of the problem by googling for the error message.

Comment: Define and declare your functions outside `main`, like in every example you’ve seen.

Comment: What are the relationships between circles and grades?  Usually they are two different assignments.

Comment: "how can find solution for the problem" taking note of the line number given would be a start.

Comment: looks as if you accidentally hit `ctrl+v` in the wrong place. Try `ctrl+z` to undo ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says what it says. Define your functions (and prototypes!) outside the `main` function.

```
#include < iostream > 

void circle(float & area, float & circumference, float r)
{
    const double pi = 3.14159;
    area = pi * r * r;
    circumference = 2 * pi * r;
}

using namespace std;
int main() {
    char grade;
    cout << "enter grade : ";
    cin >> grade;
    switch (grade) {
    case 'A':
        {
            float r, a, c;
            cout << "enter radius:";
            cin >> r;
            circle(a, c, r);
            cout << "area=" << a << "\t" << "circumference=" << c << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid grade" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Your grade is " << grade << endl;

    return 0;
}
```